# How to make xargs execute in parallel but show complete output of a single instance at a time?

Tags: bash, scripts, xargs

I am running some query commands in remote host with `xargs` in parallel which is working efficiently and very well but I have some problem in finding in which host I am getting the query from.

Right now the part of the script which is doing it, looks exactly like this:

```
export commands="cmd1; cmd2; "
hosts=("host1" "host2" "host3" "host4")
MaxInstance=10
echo_var(){
   echo "Executing in $1:"; sleep 1; echo "Output of: $commands"; return 0;
}
export -f echo_var
printf "%s\n" ${hosts[@]} | xargs -n 2 -P $MaxInstance -I {} $(command -v bash) -c 'echo_var "$1"' _ {}
```

which should output like the following because of `sleep 1`:

```
Executing in host1:
Executing in host2:
Executing in host3:
Executing in host4:
Output of: cmd1; cmd2; 
Output of: cmd1; cmd2; 
Output of: cmd1; cmd2; 
Output of: cmd1; cmd2;
```

To achieve the output that may look similar to the one shown at the end, I would have to edit the existing functions to the following to get closer to what I wanted. But even here if I use `printf "%s\n%s" "$name" "$output"` , it breaks sometimes at the new line. For example:

```
echo_var(){
 name="Executing in $1:"; sleep 1; output="Output of: $commands";
 echo -e "$name: $output" ## will work
 # echo -e "$name\n$output" ## will not work or even
 # printf "%s\n%s" "$name" "$output" ## will not work
 return 0;
}
```

Without sacrificing the rapidness of parallel execution, I would like to have the output like the following. Is there any option in `xargs` to specify to show the output of the entire instance at a time?

```
Executing in host1:
Output of: cmd1; cmd2;
Executing in host2:
Output of: cmd1; cmd2;
Executing in host3:
Output of: cmd1; cmd2;
Executing in host4: 
Output of: cmd1; cmd2;
```

Comment: why not use `&&` instead of `;`?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Tried but gives the same output

Comment: Just now, I actually found a way around to solve this problem but I do not want to do it as I am lazy.
Instead of printing the output directly, I should store all of them in variables and then output them all together side by side.

Comment: Even doing so I get new problems, which is outlined in the new edit @GeorgeUdosen

Comment: If you are running the same command on multiple hosts, checkout `parallel --nonall`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meet [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) ([`sudo apt install parallel`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/parallel)):

> GNU parallel makes sure output from the commands is the same output as
>   you would get had you run the commands sequentially.
>   If you use xargs and tee today you will find GNU parallel very easy to
>   use as GNU parallel is written to have the same options as xargs.

I can’t test it, but the command in your case should simply be:

```
parallel -n 2 -P $MaxInstance $(command -v bash) -c 'echo_var "$1"' _ {}
```

Note that the `moreutils` package provides a `parallel` command which is different from GNU parallel.

#### Example run

This example runs `echo {} start; sleep 1; echo {} ready` for the arguments `1`, `2` and `3`, first with `xargs` and then with `parallel`:

```
$ echo -e '1\n2\n3' | xargs -n1 -P3 -I{} bash -c 'echo {} start; sleep 1; echo {} ready'
2 start
1 start
3 start
2 ready
1 ready
3 ready
$ parallel 'echo {} start; sleep 1; echo {} ready' ::: 1 2 3
1 start
1 ready
2 start
2 ready
3 start
3 ready
```

Of course the `echo |` approach does work equally with `parallel`, I just like its argument list feature shown above – it does the exact same.

If you’re hesistant to use `parallel` because it’s not preinstalled, hard to install/update or anything like that I warmly recommend the program author’s blog article on [Excuses for not installing GNU Parallel](https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/).

Comment: I have a parallel command from `moreutils` is it the same ? I didn't want to use `parallel` since `xargs` comes installed and is almost everywhere.

Comment: `moreutils` 's parallel and gnu parallel is not same: https://superuser.com/q/917577/978559

Comment: @RakibFiha No, not at all. If `parallel` is not an option you really should add that information to your question.

Comment: @RakibFiha Does https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/ solve your situation? (Especially `parallel --embed`)

Comment: Actually, I still have not tried it yet, still using `xargs`, however it looks exactly what I need. I will definitely try it very soon. The only downside is that I have to install it and then perhaps might need to rename the existing `parallel` from `moreutils` to`badparallel` or something like that.

Comment: @RakibFiha If you need `moreutils` installed as well the question you linked provides [an answer to the name clash problem](https://superuser.com/a/1073444/748149): On a system <17.04 you just *force* the installation of `parallel` and it takes care of the renaming for you.